# Android: AsyncTask timeout

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timeout

Is it possible to do splash screen that will execute HTTP request and if this request is executing too long, i.e. 7-10 seconds, then abort the request and jump to the main activity?

The below code is what I did, but it doesn't work - the timeout isn't working, the HTTP request and jumping are working. As I understand, it's possible to use the `AsyncTask`'s `get()` method or handler with delay. `Get()` method should be in separate thread but it doesn't work. How to do this task?

**EDIT:**

```java
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

    if (Helpers.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Has Internet");
        final DownloadFAQ downloadFAQ = new DownloadFAQ();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Timing...");
                    downloadFAQ.execute().get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                    SplashActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "redirect");
                            redirect();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    downloadFAQ.cancel(true);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Task has benn canceled");
                    if (downloadFAQ.isCancelled())
                        redirect();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } else {

        r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                redirect();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 2500);
    }
}

private class DownloadFAQ extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Execute task");
        ServerAPI server = new ServerAPI(getApplicationContext());
        server.serverRequest(ServerAPI.GET_FAQ, null);
        return null;
    }
}

private void redirect() {
    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, TabsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
}
```

}

Comment: why you are calling downloadFAQ.get method again when AsyncTask still running ?

Comment: As I understand get() method should be called in separate thread. I tried to put this thread everywhere in doinback, in onPostExec, in main thread of activity. Itseems it doesn`t work so too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you are trying to start AsyncTask again inside `doInBackground` when it's still running . change your code as to get it work :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
    downloadFAQ = new DownloadFAQ();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    downloadFAQ.execute().get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                  SplashActivity.thisrunOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                         // start Activity here
                          Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                                                      TabsActivity.class);
                          SplashActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                          SplashActivity.this.finish();
                       }
                  });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
}
```

and you will need to remove `downloadFAQ.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` from doInBackground method change your  AsyncTask as

```
private class DownloadFAQ extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ServerAPI server = new ServerAPI(getApplicationContext());
        server.serverRequest(ServerAPI.GET_FAQ, null);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I have repost my code, it doesn`t work. But it seems that time is counting, when time is expired the exception is called. How is possible to see exactly time is counting or not?

Comment: @user1376885 : best way is put log instead Thread and asyncTask and check control flow where it's going

Comment: Thanks for all, everything what you say was very helpful for me, your timing is working correctly. Just when time is expired there is appeared timeout exception as WARNING(not error), I write what to do when this exception appeared and it`s working like a charm. Now it works so, if request cannot be passed in time, then unblock UI -> redirect to main activity, but in the background request still running until it`ll be done. For end user it`ll be great, there is no need to wait something, but I don`t know it will be too harmful for device resources or not?

Comment: @user1376885 : can i known why u are using handler.postDelayed(r, 2500);?

Comment: Just to show company logo if no internet access, only for this marketing thing=) One moment concerning my last comment, I was lie a bit, you example working absolutely correct. If time is expired and request wasn`t receive HTTP response code then it break everything and goes to main activity. But if time is expired and HTTP response code was received, then  other actions, which wasn`t managed to do everything in time, will be done in background, but user already can start enjoy the app. Great!

Answer (score 0):

consider using asyncTask status:
[AsyncTask.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html)

Comment: You don`t understand my idea. Status show only it`s running or not in general, but I need reference to time, if HTTP request executing is too long, then stop asynctask and jump in main activity. It doesn`t matter request is managed to pass everything or not.